# recursively delete all files, empty directories, and directories with files of multiple names under current directory, including current directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, files, find, rm

I am trying to delete all *.pyc and **pycache**, and any other silly files languages need to run that i don't want to see. The closest I've gotten is

```
sudo rm -rf **/*__pycache__
```

answer, which doesn't work deep down the path, and

```
sudo rm -R -f {__pycache__,.*.pyc}
```

which didn't work for **pycache** folder.

```
webapi/__pycache__
webapi/cool_app/__pycache__
webapi/cool_app/bad_file.pyc
webapi/cool_app/keep_this_awesomeness.py
webapi/cool_app/sweet_folder/__pycache__
webapi/cool_app/sweet_folder/bad_file.pyc
webapi/cool_app/sweet_folder/keep_this_awesomeness.py
```

Only

```
webapi/cool_app/keep_this_awesomeness.py 
webapi/cool_app/sweet_folder/keep_this_awesomeness.py
```

remain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
find . \( -name __pycache__ -o -name "*.pyc" \) -delete
```

Comment: I think you need parenthesis around that: `find . \( -name __pycache__ -o -name *.pyc \) -delete`

Comment: wow you guys are sick. <3

Comment: why you need the parens around?

Comment: @codyc4321 because `touch a b; find . -name a -o -name b -delete; ls a b`

Comment: ok, updated....

Comment: that just made it worse lol I was asking why does it need it

Comment: @codyc4321, because the actions in `find` are treated pretty much like the tests, and by default, the terms are combined with an `-and`. So the snippet here turns into `test1 OR test2 AND delete`, which is the same as `test1 OR ( test2 AND delete )`, and now test1 has nothing to do with the delete action. AND has priority here in the same way that multiplication has priority over addition: `1+2*3` = `1+(2*3)`. And that's because the logical AND operation is pretty much equivalent to multiplication if you look at in a certain light. I don't know if this made it any better, but there you go.

Comment: (of course `-o` is for "or" (some versions of `find` accept `-or`, too, but it's non-standard). You could use `-a` for "and" but it's not needed since it's the default.)

Answer (score 3):

If your shell supports, you can do the recursive traversal with the shell itself and use `rm` to remove the files.

For example, in `bash`, `globstar` shell option lets the glob pattern `**` to match any depth of subdirectory and also you can use regular globbing operators to match files.

In your case:

```
rm **/{*.pyc,__pycache__}
```

would do.

At first, enable `globstar`:

```
shopt -s globstar
```

Answer (score 0):

In you case, you could also do

```
find . -name "__pycache__" -o -name "*.pyc" | xargs rm -rf
```

Made only with built-in commands. It avoids you to enable globstar.